# Excel scrollbar doesn't allow screen to update until you "drop" the scrollbar

Tags: excel, office365, scrollbar

This is hopefully pretty straight forward, but after an hour of searching online, I couldn't find anyone else complaining about this issue.  Perhaps I just haven't found the right wording to describe it.

My company recently switched to Excel 2016, and I HATE the way the scrollbars work.  If you drag the scrollbar with the mouse, your current view freezes in place until you 'drop' the scrollbar.  Then the screen suddenly jumps to this part of the spreadsheet.  It used to actively display the spreadsheet as you dragged the scrollbar around, so you could see everything as you moved around.

I constantly work with enormous spreadsheets where I need to find specific sections quickly, and now that the scrollbar has become useless, it takes me much longer to navigate.

I understand you can use the arrow keys, or different shortcuts to jump through a spreadsheet, but I found the scrollbar very useful when moving through very large files.  I can't be the only person who wants this functionality turned back on, but I can't find any information on it, or any settings I can switch.

Comment: This is not a characteristic on any of my machines that use Excel 2106.  I do recall someone having this problem on an earlier version, so I doubt it is specific to the current version.  I spent some time searching through the options and find no settings related to this problem.  I believe that there was a suggestion that some setting in the registry was causing this, but I have no idea where that might be.  I am not sure, but perhaps someone has some default macros included in your install where they turn off screen updating when the scrollbars are used.

Comment: This problem with Excel 2010 sounds similar to what you are describing:  https://superuser.com/questions/800059/excel-2010-document-contents-not-scrolling-with-scrollbar

Comment: I read the link you mentioned about Excel 2010 and it is the same issue.  Unfortunately that thread ended without uncovering a solution.  However, as noted in that link, it was related to specific user(s).  I wonder if I am alone or if others in the office experience the same problem.  It could be just me I suppose.  Re: FocusWiz, I do have a personal macrobook along with an Add-In of Excel functions, but they shouldn't be affecting this.  I did add in a function to hook onto the scrollbar in a userform if the mouse is over it, but even if I remove the add-in this issue persists in Excel.

Comment: Confirmed that all users experience this problems, including users that have no add-ins or even personal macro books installed.  I even checked by creating a blank profile and opened Excel, still an issue.  Could this have something to do with the fact that we are on virtual desktops using Citrix?

Comment: Not familiar with Citrix (any more) but when I looked for hints to help you, I found references to XenDesktop that sounded similar to your problem.  If that is what you are using, you may want to try that search with "scrolling problem" as a search term.  Here is one hit:  https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/385827-office-2013-scrolling-in-xendesktop/

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I am an end user, so I don't have access to any of that, but I put a ticket in to my IT department along with the link you provided.

Answer (score 6):

This fix works for me. In Win 10 open Control Panel. Navigate to: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Centre\Make the computer easier to see. Near the bottom in the section "Make things on the screen easier to see" is a tick-box: "Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)". This was ticked for me by default so I unticked it and clicked the Apply button after which the scroll bar in Excel started to work as it does in Win 7, i.e. the cells in the background move as you drag the scrollbar left/right and up/down. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing. And I finally discovered this setting. The answer above is for an older version of Windows 10. In the current version of Windows 10 (like 21H2) the setting is now on the "Ease of Access" page under the heading "Simplify and personalize Windows", the switch is called "Show animations in Windows". It needs to be turned on.

Also, when you use Windows RDP to connect to a remote computer, it will always turn it back off on the remote computer, unless you change your RDP connection first. In RDP under the "Experience" tab, change "Detect connection quality automatically" to either "WAN (10 Mbps..." or "LAN (10 Mbps...)" and also make sure the "Menu and window animation" option is checked. Then it will stop turning this off on the remote machine every time you connect.