# Excel screen doesn't move until you "drop" the scrollbar

Tags: excel, office365, scrollbar

I requested reinstalation of my Office 365 from 32-bit to 64-bit yesterday. After that my Excel can't refresh "sheet" whenever I "drag/drop" the scrollbars (either vertical or horizontal). So basically I can click the scrollbar, go from row 10000 to 0 and the row 0 will refresh only when I release mouse button.

This question is based on this topic from few years ago: [Excel scrollbar doesn't allow screen to update until you "drop" the scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526347/excel-scrollbar-doesnt-allow-screen-to-update-until-you-drop-the-scrollbar/77095014#77095014)

I thought maybe something changed.

Best regards

I tried the solutions provided in the attached link.